# Shows exception while executing sql query in sugar

Tags: android, sql, sugarorm

I am trying to execute an sql query Sugar.But I am getting exception.
This is the query I am execting.

```
ArrayList<Folder> mFolderList = (ArrayList<Folder>) Folder.findWithQuery(Folder.class, "Select * from Folder where folderPath = " + mFileLists[i].getParent() + " and imagePath = " + mFileLists[i].getAbsolutePath());
```

Here the value for folderPath is the folder path of internal memory of device,eg: /storage/emulated/0/Download

But I am getting exception as

```
W/System.err: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "/": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: Select * from Folder where folderPath =/storage/emulated/0/Download and imagePath = /storage/emulated/0/Download/.nomedia
```

I couldn't find any error in this query.Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your image path and folder path consists of "/" and sqlite query is not accepting it..

You can use DatabaseUtils to escape this...

```
ArrayList<Folder> mFolderList = (ArrayList<Folder>) Folder.findWithQuery(Folder.class, "Select * from Folder where folderPath = " + DatabaseUtils.sqlEscapeString(mFileLists[i].getParent()) + " and imagePath = " + DatabaseUtils.sqlEscapeString(mFileLists[i].getAbsolutePath()));
```